# Рисование 3D графиков в RStudio пакет rgl

Tags: r, rstudio

Помогите с отрисовкой графика. Я могу вывести точки, но мне надо что то похоже на график на картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
set.seed(123)

x<-as.numeric(runif(10,190,280))
y<-as.numeric(runif(10,1,11))
z<-as.numeric(c(1:10))
for(i in z){
  z[i]<-sqrt((x[i]^2)/25-3*(y[i]^2))
}
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
names(df)<-c(xn,yn,zn)
rgl.open()
rgl.points(df$x,df$y,df$z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А обязательно в `rgl`? Я приведу пример в `plot3D`, а Вы в крайнем случае там адаптируйте под `rgl`.

Вот Ваши данные:

```
set.seed(123)

x<-as.numeric(runif(10,190,280))
y<-as.numeric(runif(10,1,11))
z<-as.numeric(1:10)
for(i in z){
  z[i]<-sqrt((x[i]^2)/25-3*(y[i]^2))
}
```

Мы уже можем сделать график:

```
library(plot3D)
scatter3D(x, y, z, 
          xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z")
```

[image: график с точками]

Но Вы хотите сделать целую плоскость, а для этого Вам ее нужно смоделировать. Я построю линейную регрессию, хотя можно и какую-нибудь еще.

```
fit <- lm(z ~ x + y)
```

Теперь давайте сделаем нашу сетку для этого построим по 10 точек (можно больше, замените значение аргумента `length.out`) в пределах каждой переменной (можно в каких-то других пределах, тогда замените `min()` и `max()` на что-нибудь):

```
x.pred <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 10)
y.pred <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = 10)
xy <- expand.grid(x = x.pred, y = y.pred)
z.pred <- matrix(predict(fit, newdata = xy), nrow = 10)
```

Теперь мы готовы нарисовать плоскость:

```
scatter3D(x, y, z, 
          xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z",  
          surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.pred))
```

[image: график с плоскостью]

Ну и дальше остались всякие мелочи, типа как покрутить график, это Вы уж сами легко найдете в интернете, например, [здесь](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization).

Comment: Спасибо! Лучшее решение которое нашел